Problema al exportar vistas de un esquema en mysql
Muy buenas, tengo un problema al exportar vistas de un esquema en mysql 5.7 para ser importado en myql 8.2. El problema es que la vista exportada está escribiendo los datos de las vistas con valores de columna fijos del tipo
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dim_clientes`;
/*!50001 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `dim_clientes`*/;
SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client;
SET character_set_client = utf8;
/*!50001 CREATE VIEW `dim_clientes` AS SELECT 
 1 AS `id_dimusu`,
 1 AS `fecha_captura`,
 1 AS `keyusu_vip`,
 1 AS `keyempresa_vip`,
 1 AS `nombre_usu`, .."

Cuando la vista es
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `aa_datamart_jm`.`dim_clientes` AS
    SELECT 
        `aa_datamart_jm`.`dim_usuarios`.`id_dimusu` AS `id_dimusu`,
        `aa_datamart_jm`.`dim_usuarios`.`fecha_captura` AS `fecha_captura`,
        `aa_datamart_jm`.`dim_usuarios`.`keyusu` AS `keyusu_vip`,
        `aa_datamart_jm`.`dim_usuarios`.`keyempresa` AS `keyempresa_vip`,
        `aa_datamart_jm`.`dim_usuarios`.`nombre` AS `nombre_usu`, ..

He probado desde el workbench, heidi, MF y el resultado fue simpre el mismo
Al usar comandos desde mydump
mysqldump -u root -p aa_datamart_jm --no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db --skip-triggers --routines=false --events=false --no-tablespaces --tables v1 v2 > "C:/export/datamart_jm_solo_vistas_240806_manual.sql"

ha sido un archivo vacío con solo las cabeceras
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.39, for Win64 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: aa_datamart_jm
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.7.39-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2024-08-06 10:21:39"

Alguna sugerencia?

Una forma de lograrlo usando mysql desde la línea de comandos es:
mysql -u [USERNAME] -p --skip-column-names --batch -e "SELECT CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME, '; CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME, ' AS ', VIEW_DEFINITION, '; ') AS table_name FROM information_schema.VIEWS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '[DB_NAME]'" > views.sql

Donde:

[USERNAME] tenes que reemplazarlo por le nombre del usuario, en tu caso sería root.
[DB_NAME] tenes que reemplazarlo por el nombre de la base de datos, en tu caso sería aa_datamart_jm


Referencia:

Respuesta original: SO > Backing Up Views with Mysql Dump


Muchas gracias https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/16597/marcos efectivamente funciona tu acertada respuesta. Lo he probado y genera un archivo sql con todas las consultas. Creo que el problema original estaba asociado a vistas que tiraban de otras vistas definidas a posteriori por lo que al no poder generarla realizaba esa sustitución. Me imagino que algún problema dará la recuperación del archivo generado en tu respuesta por la misma causa pero esta claro que esta es una vía válida.

Lamentablemente entre mi pregunta y tu respuesta he ido una a una copiando y generando las vistas entre los dos esquemas teniendo en cuenta los ordenes de prelación de las vistas, por lo que no he podido hacer una prueba con tu respuesta. Aun así creo que es válida. Un saludo y gracias @Marcos
